# ComboBox.SelectionChanged doesn't catch the first selection

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, combobox

I need to fill textboxes depending on the item selected in a combobox. I fill combo async and in Completed event I have the following code

```
combo.ItemsSource = e.Result;
combo.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
combo.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Then in the SelectionChanged event of the combo, I catch the selected object

```
MyClass mc= ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem as MyClass;
tbxName.Text = mc.Name;
...
```

However, when I load the project and select any event for the 1st time, NOTHING happens. Every other time (2nd, 3rd, nth) the data is correctly caught and displayed.

So I need to know why the combo doesn't catch the first selection? That's the reason I have the code *combo.SelectedIndex = -1* (when the app loads, combo is empty - selection -1 works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by putting the code inside Completed event. Now I have delay in executing everything, but it works.